# How to disable web security on Opera browser?

Tags: security, browser, opera

I'm working on the version `89.0.4447.83` of Opera. I disabled web security on Opera on Windows 10 so I could retrieve information from web pages loaded in my iframe on my localhost. For this I used the following command:

```
cd c:\Program Files\Opera\
    launcher.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:\nocorsbrowserdata"
```

However, when I try to fetch the content of a webpage, I get the error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

In order to check if Opera was reading the headers web security, I tried to load a website that did not allow connection in an iframe namely google and I got the error: `www.google.com refused to connect`. I don't understand why web security is not disabled yet I used the correct command.